# Navigation Link Set: Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires

Tags: trigger, community, error, dml

I am trying and deploy a `Navigation Link Set`

But, I am getting error message:

> Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers. Number of retries: 2

This is a strange error message because it seems to be related to triggers or DML, but the metadata type relates to communities.

The changeset does include a trigger, but it's a before trigger without `DML`

And there is not batch saves in org or changeset.

1. Any idea why it's happening?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why it's happening?

You have cascading errors. The system tries to save three times (original request plus two retries). If any components fail in the first batch, another pass is attempted without them. If any further components fail, one more attempt is given. If there are yet more errors, the system gives up.

> How can I fix it?

Use the "Add Dependencies" button to make sure you're not missing anything. You can also check the Deployment Status screen in the destination org and see if any other errors were logged as well.